# How to connect MediaControler to MediaPlayer as a service

Tags: android

I have an application based on fragments where the MediaPlayer is implemented as a service.
I'd like to use the mediaController.
I'm in the same case as explained here ([Android: How to use mediaController in service class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001183/android-how-to-use-mediacontroller-in-service-class)). I think.

My application setup the mediacontroller like that:
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mPlayMediaService = binder.getService();
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getActivity(), Fragment_playMedias.class);

        am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);

        site.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity(),false));
        site.getMediaController().setAnchorView(getView().findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutAudioControl));
        site.getMediaController().setMediaPlayer(this);
        site.getMediaController().setEnabled(true);
        site.getMediaController().show();
        mBound = true;
   }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

I don't know it the API changed recently but the it's not possible to setMediaPlayer() with the reference returned by binder.getService().

Eclipse says: The method setMediaPlayer(MediaController.MediaPlayerControl) in the type MediaController is not applicable for the arguments (new ServiceConnection(){})

So I wonder how the author get it working!?!

Any idea?

Regards,
Alain

Comment: that part `implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` gets it working...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what it's suppose to change to setMediaPlayer(mPlayMediaService);. The error is still the same.

Comment: you call `setMediaPlayer(this);`. Unless `this` is an instance of a class that `implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl`, this will produce this error.

Comment: ok, and I suppose that I'll have to use the MediaplayerControl methods to control the service? I tried but I cannot get the controller displayed... I'm going to investigate... Thks

Comment: @caBBAlainB any updates?

Comment: @danielgomezrico unfortunately not, I gave it up as it wasn't a priority for me. I use my own buttons.