# Android - Set view for a class, not extending Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, view

How can I create and set a View for a class that doesnt extend activity? 
 
 **My 'MyServiceIntent' class extends IntentService, rather than Activity.**

How can I change the current view in the MyServiceIntent class? Currently it just shows Main's view. But I need a new view shown in my MyServiceIntent class.

I tried:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)
```

but I cant call it as my 'MyServiceIntent' class doesn't extend Activity.

I also tried static 'MyServiceIntent'  class, but it wasn't able to access the view data from the main class.

Thanks

Comment: You want a different layout when you start the service? If so, then start a new activity and then start the service from the new activity. or do you want access to views from another activity? Can you repeat more precisely what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah, we definitely need more information. Are you sure you want a service and not just a new activity?

Comment: You have to have an Activity at some point. Services are designed to run in the background, Activities are designed to house the UI.

Comment: thank you T.S and everyone. I've fixed it. I created a new activity like T.S said

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

However, you can still alter the view of a running activity from the service! For this you should bind the activity and the service. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001183/android-how-to-use-mediacontroller-in-service-class/10768417#10768417) for some example code